# Alert in JavaScript not read by ChromeVox Classic Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function AlertUser()
{   
    alert("Hello World");
}
```

This is a sample alert in javascript. I was using ChromeVox Classic Extension to read the content inside the alert. It is working perfectly fine, reading out loud, when Windows Narrator was used. But when using ChromeVox Classic Extension to read, the content inside the alert is not read out loud.

Comment: which browser you are using, with chrome vox?

Comment: Google Chrome .

Comment: for IE11 use -> JAWS,

for FireFox use-> NVDA,
for Chrome use->NVDA or JAWS,
for Safari use ->Voice Over,
for Edge use -> Narrator

Answer (score 0):

Browsers and suitable screen Readers

1. IE11 use JAWS
2. FIREFOX  use  NVDA
3. CHROME   use  NVDA/JAWS
4. SAFARI  use  Voice Over
5. Edge     use Narrator